# Clarification on increasing sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that there is a shared domain $E$, such that $ F_{n}(x) = F(x)$ on $ A \subset E $ and $0$ otherwise. Is a sequence of function considered *increasing* if $ \mathrm{Range}(F_{n+1}) \supset \mathrm{Range}(F_{n}) $, of is it as $ n \to +\infty$  for$ \forall \  x  \in E$ $ F_{n+1}(x) \geqslant F_{n}(x)$?

Comment: There doesn't have to be a single notion of increasing - nuance and multiple interpretations of the word "increasing" lead to different ideas, each of which can be valuable.

Comment: I am studying  basic measure thoery from Royden 45h ed, and I am not sure in what sense they mean increasing for many of the theorems, unless both sense as above lead to the same results, agian clarity is lacking on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence $f_n: E \to \Bbb R$ of functions is increasing if $n > m $ implies $f_n(x) \geqslant f_m(x)$, for all $x \in E$. For example, $f_n = \chi_{[0, n[}$ is increasing, and $f_n \uparrow \chi_{[0, + \infty [}$. It might be instructive to prove this last fact (fix $x \in \Bbb R$, let $\epsilon > 0 $, find $n_0 \geqslant 1 $ such that...).

Comment: As there has been discussion about different notions of “increasingness” I just want to point out that this is the measure theoretic definition that OP wants. It’s very important for the Beppo Levi Theorem and standard procedure proofs (approximation of functions by increasing simple functions) in measure theory.

Comment: Yes, I gave this answer after seeing OP's comment about measure theory. I'm taking this class this semester and this is definition we use, at least here.